# How can I draw several ROI's using imfreehand?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I need to draw several ROI's using the **imfreehand** function in MATLAB R2015a. What I need is to plot an image and the user must select as many ROI's as he/she wants and when they are done, they must click (right mouse button) in order to finish the selection. Also, the user must be able to select a desired ROI and delete it.

Can anyone here, please, give me examples or any idea about how I can implement this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you hit escape instead of a right-click to end it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `ButtonDownFcn` callback for the axes. Whenever the user clicks the left mouse button, you allow them to start drawing a new ROI. When they click the right mouse button it stops and returns a list of `imfreehand` objects. When you right click on an ROI, there is a context menu that would allow them to delete a given ROI.

```
function handles = multiROI()

    hax = axes('ButtonDownFcn', @(src,evnt)buttondown(evnt))

    handles = [];

    % Keep this function open until we right click
    waitfor(gca, 'UserData')

    function buttondown(evnt)
        switch evnt.Button
            case 1      
                % On a left click draw a new ROI
                handles = cat(1, handles, imfreehand());
            case 3
                % On a right click, remove empty ROIs and return
                handles = handles(isvalid(handles));
                set(gca, 'UserData', 'done')
        end
    end
end
```

**Update**

Here is a version that doesn't require as many clicks but uses the escape key to finish drawing.

```
handles = imfreehand();
lastroi = handles;

while ~isempty(lastroi)
    lastroi = imfreehand();
    handles = cat(1, handles, lastroi);
end

handles = handles(isvalid(handles));
```

Comment: Thank you! But I tried your code but seems it is not working properly. There is a kind of a lag when I click on the image and takes some clicks until I can draw something...

Comment: @Gabs Yes you have to click to activate the `imfreehand` and then click again and hold to draw.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid so many clicks? I mean, once I draw a ROI, the GUI is ready to draw another one without the need of clicking and click and hold?

Comment: @Gabs You can easily call `imfreehand` within a `while` loop but you won't be able to register right clicks. That's why I commented on your initial post asking if you can hit escape rather than a right click. Also if you do it in a loop, you will be unable to delete existing ROIs

Comment: @Gabs I have updated it with an example of that approach

Comment: Yes, but that is the point: the user must interact with the GUI only using the mouse...

Comment: @Gabs Then you need to write a custom ROI object